# SQL Error (1064) : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Tags: php, mysql, database, heidisql

I have a sql file name live.sql and I want import in my DB in `heidiSQL` but when I am going import this file, it gives a following error.

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near
>   'þFFvar/www/html/live/databases/012017/live_01_11_2017.sql
>   ' at line 1

How can I fix this error?

[image]

Comment: Without knowing the content of the file it's impossible to tell. With that said, the error itself is self explanatory. You have an error in the SQL syntax.,

Comment: What's the first line in you SQL file supposed to do? Importing other SQL files is not as simple as that.

Comment: update your question and add the related  sql code ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that the sql query is incorrect. Comment out line number 1, by adding 2 dashes (--) at the start of the line.